# Check the sum of particular fields in multiple Mongoose collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make a reservation mongoose schema for the restaurant but I don't want people to be able to place a reservation if 'people' value is more than 50 in all collections.

```
var reservationSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    people: Number,
    date: String,
    name: String,
    email: String
});

var Reservation = mongoose.model("Reservation", reservationSchema);

app.post('/reservation', (req, res) => {
    var people = parseFloat(req.body.people);
    var date = req.body.date;
    var name = req.body.name;
    var email = req.body.email;   

    var newReservation = {people: people, date: date, name: name, email: email};
    Reservation.create(newReservation, (err, newlyCreated) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } 
        else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    })
});
```

How to filter through all collection to find what is the number when you add up all the values from people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use aggregation pipeline to sum the number of people. If the count is less than 50, create new reservation, else show some message.

For this you can use `statics` method.

```
var reservationSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    people: Number,
    date: String,
    name: String,
    email: String
});


reservationSchema.statics = {
    createIfSpaceAvailable : function(newReservation, done){
        var Reservation = this;
        Reservation.aggregate([
        {
         $group:{
             _id: null,
             noOfPeople: { $sum: "$people"}
         }
        }], 
        function(err, result){
        if(err){
            return done(err);
        }
        else if(result[0].noOfPeople > 50){
            // do something
        }
        else{
            Reservation.create(newReservation, (err, newlyCreated) => {
                if(err) {
                     return done(err);
                } 
                else {
                     return done();
                }
            })
        }
    })
   }
};
var Reservation = mongoose.model("Reservation", reservationSchema);

app.post('/reservation', (req, res) => {
    var people = parseFloat(req.body.people);
    var date = req.body.date;
    var name = req.body.name;
    var email = req.body.email;   

    var newReservation = {people: people, date: date, name: name, email: email};
    Reservation.createIfSpaceAvailable(newReservation, (err, newlyCreated) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } 
        else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Why `_id: null`?

Comment: @TalhaAwan Thank you for answer but i get TypeError: Cannot read property 'noOfPeople' of undefined.

Comment: @JKshort, `console.log(result)` to check how data is being returned. I'm not sure it's `result.noOfPeople` or `result[0].noOfPeople`

Comment: @TalhaAwan It is result[0].noOfPeople, I did not put anything in else if statement, maybe that was causing problem but it works now. Thanks

Comment: After all it wasn't mistake, fucntion is working but i need to have at leas one collection in database. If it is empty it trow error

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregation pipeline - see:

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/

and specifically the `$sum` operator:

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/

By the way, since Node v4.x instead of writing:

```
var newReservation = {people: people, date: date, name: name, email: email};
```

you can use a shorter syntax:

```
var newReservation = {people, date, name, email};
```

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer